# Activity должна "исчезнуть" при сворачивании

Tags: android, activity

Одна из `Activity` отображает данные, которые не должны оставаться "без присмотра".
Мучал флаги и атрибуты - не выходит.
Вызывал `finish()` в `onPause()` - сама активность закрывается, но в таске висит её скриншот и данные можно прочесть.

Comment: очищать данные в onPause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оказалось можно скрыть контент в превью флагом окна

```
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
           setContentView(R.layout.main);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Это конечно так себе... из ряда вон, но почему бы и нет )
В один общий `RelativeLayout` положите 2 вью, первый какой вам угодно для элементов вашего экрана, второй к примеру `FrameLayout` с черным цветом. Ну а дальше у `FrameLayout` просто в `onResume` и `onPause` меняйте `visibility (GONE \ VISIBLE)`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!--тут все остальные ваши вью-->
    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/black_screen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Я пробовал менять UI в `onPause()` - скриншот снимается где-то раньше

Comment: а вы до super.onPause() вызываете ?)

Comment: Даже ДО `onPause()` - в `onUserLeaveHint()` пробовал.